# How do I get an image from an sdcard to show up on a widget imageview?

Tags: android, android-widget, imageview, remoteview

I am trying to make it so that the widget shows an image saved onto the sdcard. so far i have found this:

```
String imageInSD = String.format("/sdcard/facepalm%d.jpeg", counter%10);    
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageInSD);
remoteViews.setBitmap(R.id.imageview1, "setImageBitmap", bitmap);
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

The commented line causes the widget to crash for some reason. I just want to find a way to make this work.

Comment: Hardcoding your image's location to `/sdcard` is not a good idea. In a lot of new devices, the sdcard is mounted under `/emmc`

Comment: it may be helpful to add that i am completely new to android so... i dont even know what im doing...

Comment: to the OP, I suggest you read up the basics and fundamentals of this before embarking on this otherwise you'd just get frustrated and give up. There's plenty of resources out there, in fact, I recommend Commonsware series, to give you an overview of Android, fundamentals of Java etc :)

Comment: but i want to know why you are decoding image to Bitmap because it's possible to set image directly in ImageView from SD-CARD without decoding it to Bitmap using Image URI?

Comment: http://commonsware.com/ that's where I learnt mine from among other resources :) really I should not be advertising that per se... but hey, its my recommendation and word of mouth... the SO user commonsware would be quite pleased :) :P

Comment: @imran khan how do i do that?

Comment: @MathewVejarMiravite : see my answer or if you are decoding Image to Bitmap then be Careful this maybe cause memory Leaks for your Application. Declare Bitmap as WeakReference because using it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try as no need to decode image to Bitmap,just get URI of image from image path:

```
File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/XX/facepalm%d.jpeg");
Uri  imgUri=Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
ImageView  imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageuri);
imageView.setImageURI(imgUri);
```

Comment: this solved it and i thank you though i didnt exactly use all of it i only used  
 File tempFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/XX/facepalm%d.jpeg");
Uri  imgUri=Uri.fromFile(tempFile);

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
    if(isSDPresent)
    {
       String pathOfImageInSD = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/"+"facepalm.png";
       bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathOfImageInSD);
    }
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview1);
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```